# NativeScript: Augment tns-platform-declarations

Tags: android, typescript, nativescript

In my NativeScript project i want to include `RecyclerView` from Android Support Library.
I included the dependency in `app/App_Resources/Android/app.gradle` :

```
// Uncomment to add recyclerview-v7 dependency
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
}
```

From [git issue#2295](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2295) and other related issues, i read that `tns-platform-declarations` can be included to offer definition files for native android/ios libraries.
So i installed them and followed [tns platform declarations documentation](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/tree/master/tns-platform-declarations)

I want to compile following example snippet:

```js
import { ContentView } from "ui/content-view";

declare var android: any;

export class OptimizedListView extends ContentView {

  private _android: android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

  public _createUI() {
    this._android = new android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView(this._context);
  }

};
```

Declaring the `var android` like above cleans up the second reference of `RecyclerView`. But the following error on the top reference of RecyclerView remains:

> message: 'Namespace 'android.support.v7.widget' has no exported member
>   'RecyclerView'.'

I also tried declaring the RecyclerView class without success:

```
export declare class RecyclerView extends ContentView {}
```

I am aware of the fact, that `tns-platform-declarations` has definitions until `android.support.v7.widget`.

Workaround of "noEmitOnError" set to false feels not right.

So how can i extend this declaration to `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView` without compile issues?

Versions:

- "nativescript-dev-typescript": "^0.3.2"
- "tns-platform-declarations":    "^2.4.0-2016-09-28-1"
- "typescript": "^2.1.1"
- "tns-core-modules":    "next"

Answer (score 1):

Finally I did not go with `tns-platform-declarations` at all, because performance was very bad (especially if you have <= 8GB RAM in your dev machine).

My solution was to define a own `my-typings.d.ts` file (e.g. in the project root dir) in which I defined the augmenting type `RecyclerView`. With `tsconfig.json` defaults it should be automatically be caught up by `tsc`. Otherwise `exclude` / `include`, or `files` expressions can be added.

Then you can place a `/// <reference path="path/to/RecyclerView/file.d.ts" />` inside, so that the following `ambient global namespace` can be found by Typescript compiler.

```
declare namespace android {

  namespace view {
    namespace ViewGroup {
      namespace LayoutParams {
        const MATCH_PARENT;
        const WRAP_CONTENT;
      }
    }
    class ViewGroup {

    }
  }

  namespace support.v7.widget {

    namespace RecyclerView {
      type AdapterImpl = {
        onCreateViewHolder(parent: android.view.ViewGroup, viewType: number): ViewHolder;
        onBindViewHolder(holder: android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: number): void;
        getItemCount(): number
      };

      class Adapter {
        static extend(AdapterImpl): { new () }
      }

      class LayoutParams {
        constructor(width: any, height: any);
      }

      class ViewHolder {
        static extend: any;
      }
    }

    class RecyclerView {
      constructor(context: any);

      setAdapter(Adapter): void;
      setLayoutManager(LinearLayoutManager): void;
    }

    class LinearLayoutManager {
      constructor(context: any);
    }

  }
}
```

Basically, namespaces can be used to emulate nested object properties (e.g. `android.view.xxx`). This is also the way, if inner classes are defined in Java (Typescript seems to forbid nested `class`statements).

I also had to define a class with the same name as the namespace in cases, where I actually use the type (like in `android.view.ViewGroup`). Otherwise you get above error

> no exported member xxx

, even if the class type is explicitly declared with `export` (and it's not necessary, because you have globally declared the namespace).

For the special case of extending native Java types with `extend`, I defined a static method for the relevant classes like `static extend(AdapterImpl): { new () }`, whose return type can be instantiated with `new`.

Hope, that helps other with similar issues.

Comment: I kind of don't like this answer-- I want it to be correct. Why bother importing the entire native platforms if code completion doesn't work?

Comment: I made a question for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43079773/how-to-use-the-native-android-widgets-type-definitions-in-nativescript